# pycharm type checker expected type dict, got 'None' instead

Tags: python, pycharm, typechecking

In this snippet:

```
from typing import Dict, Optional 
class T:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bla = {}

    def t(self) -> Dict:
        if self.bla is None:
            self.bla = {'not none': 'nope!'}
        return self.bla
```

Can anyone explain why intellij / pycharm's type checker thinks the return value of this method is `None`?

[image: code snippet with error message]

The type checker only seems satisfied if I annotate the return type of `t()` to be `Optional[Dict]`, but this method can never return `None`, so I don't think it should be optional.

If I change the initial value of `self.bla` in `__init__()` to `{}` it still things the return value is `None`. Same error if I use a `str` instead of a `dict`

Comment: Probably it is because of `if self.bla is None` check in your code.

Comment: The `if self.bla:` is immediately followed by `self.bla = ____`, no code path can leave it `None`

Comment: Man, python is a dynamically typed language. You could override `__setattr__` attribute so `self.bla` will set your `bla` to None, for example. 
I think pycharm's behaviour is consistent.

Comment: If that is the case, then why would the type checker be so certain `self.bla` is `None`? I know python is dynamic and that you can go deep into cloud-coo-coo-land, but the type checker can only work with what it sees. With that in mind, can you say why the test for `None` makes it think value is still `None` when it's clearly changed to something that isn't?

Comment: It's more that the type checker cannot be certain it I _not_ None, came across this looking to resolve an issue where it can be None and so I used Optional[dict]

Answer (score 25):

With the following `-> Dict or None` annotation pycharm (2019.2) does not complain and I get `dict` type autocompletion for `fdictnoneres`:

```py
def fdictnone() -> Dict or None:
    return dict(a=1, b=2)


fdictnoneres = fdictnone()
```

When using `TypeVar` pycharm does not provide `dict` type autocompletion for `tfunres`:

```py
from typing import TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T', dict, None)


def tfun() -> T:
    return dict(a=1, b=2)


tfunres = tfun()
```

Comment: Your solution definitely works the best for whoever has a new enough version of pycharm

Comment: Dict or None, did not you can do the 'or' thing! Thats great to know

Comment: I'm not sure why None is treated differently when a variable can have None value until proper value gets assigned to it.

Comment: PyCharm 2020.3.2 does not autocomplete "List or None" for me :( Screenshot - https://i.ibb.co/wRqbZnc/2021-02-04-17-01-38.png

Answer (score 5):

What you *CAN* do, but shouldn't, is this:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bla = {}

    def t(self) -> dict:
        if self.bla is None:
            result = {'not none': 'nope!'}
            self.bla = result
            return result
        else:
            return self.bla
```

This way, the variables are recognised separately. Note however, that this solution is stupid -- you're just doing a workaround for what I would consider a bug in PyCharm! In fact, I have the same problem and still no solution...

For now I would suggest either ignoring the warning or forcing PyCharm to ignore it by adding:

```
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
```

I have read somewhere, that the type hinting is not fully implemented yet in PyCharm, so that might still come... I don't remember where I read this though, so no guarantee!

Comment: This "shouldn't do" is exactly what I am doing to make it type check :) but I agree.

Answer (score 2):

I found Type hinting the instance variable works.   I also don't seem to incur the original inspection error in the 2018 pro version of pycharm, so I'm wondering if they've updated the inspection to be a little smarter.

```py
class T(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bla:Dict = None

    def t(self) -> Dict:
        if self.bla is None:
            self.bla = {'foo' : 'bar'}
        return self.bla
```

Comment: `self.bla: Dict = None` gives me `Expected type 'dict', got 'None' instead` in PyCharm 2021.2.1 (Community Edition). :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because it is initialized as None on your constructor.
I believe if you explicitly state the type in the class definition it should work. Eg:

```
class T:
    bla: Dict

    def __init__(self):
        self.bla = None
```